# Who was Charles Kingston O'Mahony?

Tags: 20th-century, british-empire, ireland

I've read his book [*The Viceroys of Ireland*](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/36193) and am trying to find out more about him. The book was published in 1912 and I can't find any more information about him.

I was able to dig up references to two people who might or might not be him:

1. A [writer](https://www.google.co.il/search?tbo=p&tbm=bks&q=inauthor%3a%22Charles%20Kingston%20%28%5Bi.e.%20Charles%20Kingston%20O%27Mahony.%5D%29%22) who published many detective books in the period 1925-1941.
2. A priest who [helped De Valera escape from prison](http://radicalmanchester.wordpress.com/2009/08/24/paddy-o%E2%80%99donoghue/):

> Collins and Boland went to London and then back to Dublin. The others
>   journeyed back to Manchester by way of Sheffield. Milroy and McGarry
>   were hidden by leading Manchester IRA commander Liam MacMahon in his
>   own house, while De Valera stayed with a local priest, Father Charles
>   O’Mahony. The police were looking for De Valera, of course, and
>   MacMahon was warned by Thomas Walsh, a sympathetic detective in the
>   Manchester force, that they were getting close. On 18th February,
>   dressed as a priest and escorted by two young Irish women, De Valera
>   travelled back to Dublin. At the beginning of June he went to the
>   United States.

However, the first one seems to have little connection to Irish affairs, by the titles of his books, and the second one doesn't sound like the author of the book I've read (but who knows...).

Comment: Felix, have you ever seen on Google Books? Since there I found a lot of books talking about such a Charles Kingston O'Mahony, I suggest you to get a preliminary research.

Comment: Here's the worldcat union author record: http://www.worldcat.org/search?q=au%3AO%27Mahony%2C+Charles+Kingston%2C+1884-&qt=hot_author and here's his grave http://www.gravestonephotos.com/public/gravedetails.php?available=yes&fullname=Charles%20Kingston%20O'Mahony&grave=101693&personid=221869&db=101693

Comment: @SamuelRussell: But which of the Charles O'Mahonys is buried there?

Comment: Worldcat indicates a birth date in the union record.  The union record author's last book was published immediately prior to the death date on that grave, which bears the same birth date.  You've got a location to look for local newspaper obits now.

Comment: @SamuelRussell: Am I right in surmising he is not the one who wrote detective books?

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1560/the-time-machine

Answer (score 2):

I am going to catalog the results above because comments sometimes get deleted, and are not intended to be part of the permanent record for a question.

- [The Online Books Page](http://onlinebooks.library.upenn.edu/webbin/book/lookupname?key=O%27Mahony,%20Charles%20Kingston,%201884-) for Charles Kingston O'Mahoney, 1884-
- [All entries for the name O'Mahoney at GravestonePhotos.com](http://www.gravestonephotos.com/public/findfamily.php?name=O%27Mahony)
- [Charles Kingston O'Mahoney grave monument details](http://www.gravestonephotos.com/public/gravedetails.php?available=yes&fullname=Charles%20Kingston%20O%27Mahony&grave=101693&personid=221869&db=101693) (now 1884-1944)
- Project Gutenberg: [The Viceroys of Ireland by Charles Kingston O'Mahoney](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/36193/36193-h/36193-h.htm)
- [Detective novels by Charles Kingston](https://www.google.co.il/search?tbo=p&tbm=bks&q=inauthor%3a%22Charles+Kingston+%28%5Bi.e.+Charles+Kingston+O%27Mahony.%5D%29%22) (noted on site as also Charles Kingston O'Mahoney)
- [1920 US Census lists a Charles Omahoney](http://search.ancestry.com/cgi-bin/sse.dll?rank=1&new=1&MSAV=0&msT=1&gss=angs-c&gsln=O%27mahony&uidh=000&gl=usfedcen&gst=&ghc=20&fh=280&fsk=BEFn5CkIgAAXrQRFSRU-61-), born about 1884, living in Bronx, NY
- [1930 US Census lists a Charles O'Mahoney, spouse Helen O'Mahoney, born about 1882](http://search.ancestry.com/cgi-bin/sse.dll?rank=1&new=1&MSAV=0&msT=1&gss=angs-c&gsln=O%27mahony&uidh=000&gl=usfedcen&gst=&ghc=20&fh=160&fsk=BEFmZmYIgAAYUATzKSc-61-), living in Bronx NY

**Update** - from an anonymous contributor:

> Charles O'Mahony in the 1930 US Census Bronx NY is my mother's uncle. He was married to Helen Zacbek. He was born in Nenagh, Co. Tipperary, Ireland 1881 and died in the Bronx NY 1942. He is not Charles Kingston O'Mahony.
>   *Seamus Murray Dublin*